# How to translate boolean expressions to three address code?

Tags: compilers

There are two uses of a boolean expression in a language like C, one as a condition in flow of control statements and the other as boolean value in assignment and arithmetic expressions.

I was studying the translation of boolean expressions into three address code from the Dragon Book.

Now, I came across the following text and I seriously just don’t understand what the authors are trying to convey here. Could somebody please clarify for me?

> A clean way of handling both roles of boolean expressions is to first build a syntax tree for expressions, using either of the following approaches:
>
> 1. *Use two passes*. Construct a complete syntax tree for the input, and then walk the tree in depth-first order, computing the translations specified by the semantic rules.
> 2. *Use one pass for statements, but two passes for expressions.* With this approach, we would translate $E$ in **while** ($E$) $S_{1}$ before $S_{1}$ is examined. The translation of $E$, however, would be done by building its syntax tree and then walking the tree.

Comment: Please spend 10 minutes transcribing your text. It is very hard to read at the moment (since it's sideways), and it's not searchable.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Done.